# multiple scan buttons Zxing

Tags: java, android, zxing

I'm working on a small Android project .. I have the Xzing barcode scanners linked and everything worked. now I need again a scann-button. But when I scan with the second button, it writes me the result in the same field as the first scann-button.can someone help me?

```
package de.example.addmeter;





@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);     //Fullscreen
        setContentView(R.layout.add_strom);

        }



        public void onClick1 (View view) {
            IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);
            integrator.initiateScan();
        }

        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
              IntentResult scanResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
              if (scanResult != null) {

                  String meterid;   


              meterid = scanResult.getContents();



                EditText etmeterid = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etmeterid);

                etmeterid.setText(meterid);
              }  
            }


        public void onClick2 (View view) {
            IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);
            integrator.initiateScan();
        }
        public void onActivityResult1(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
              IntentResult scanResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
              if (scanResult != null) {

                  String security;  


              security = scanResult.getContents();

              EditText etsecurity = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etsecurity);

                etsecurity.setText(security);
              }  
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

That `onActivityResult1` function is never called. When the Xzing intent returns, you have to manage all the result code in `onActivityResult` (that, by the way, should be marked as `@Override`).

Normally, what you want should be managed whith different `requestCode`, but seems that Xzing intent helper does not allow it.

So, in your case, I would make something like setting a global boolean variable `wasCalledFromButton1`, giving it a value in the corresponding `onClick` method, an then give the returned value to the correct EditText in `onActivityResult` according to this variable.